# Is there an easy way in Xcode to remove the completion block from the end?

Tags: swift, xcode, completionhandler

Every Swift function with a completion handler on the end like so:

```
func hello(_ name: String, completionHandler: (String) -> Void) {
    completionHandler("Hello \(name).")
}
```

Can be called like:

```
hello("Stack Overflow", completionHandler: { text in
    print(text)
})
// Prints Hello Stack Overflow.
```

But also simpler:

```
hello("Stack Overflow") { text in
    print(text)
}
// Prints Hello Stack Overflow.
```

But when writing code in Xcode and you start typing hello, you will get the full function. Is there an easy shortcode which you can press to immediately remove the completionHandler from the function or do you have to this manually?

Comment: Note that if you double click on the placeholder for the `completionHandler` you should get the last version (with the explicit param and "in" though).

Comment: When you tab to the last item in the function signature, press enter and it will automatically convert it to a trailing closure like your simpler example.

Comment: You are talking about two different things: The **trailing closure** syntax and the **shorthand** (`$0`) syntax. You get the former for free as suggested by the others but you don't get the latter.

Comment: @Larme I wasn't aware of that thanks.

Comment: @Andrew that was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @vadian you are correct I edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type *hello* if the correct function method appears in the suggestions list press `ENTER`. The full method will appear and you will get.

[image]

**Keyboard:** `CTRL + /` to the completion handler `(String) -> Void` and press `ENTER`.

**Mouse:** Double click on the text `(String) -> Void>)`.

[image]

Comment: Does it still work on Xcode 15? Seems the behavior is changed to having completion handler by default